# Почему Google Play (андроид) не видит интернет по wi-fi, но видит его через передачу данных по gsm?

Tags: android

Очень странная ситуация - на смартфоне android приложение Google Play говорит нет доступа к интернету если смартфон подключен к моему роутеру по wi-fi. Некоторые другие приложения Google говорят то же самое. При чем приложения не связанные с гуглом к интернету подключаются даже через wifi.

Есть еще такой странный момент: если подключиться по wi fi к другому роутеру, то приложения Google видят интернет! Также они видят интернет если отключиться от wifi и подключить интернет через передачу данных gsm 4g.

Сброс роутера (восстановление ранее сохраненных настроек) и сброс android сделал, не помогло.

Что происходит?

Comment: может у вас роутер показывает только сигнал, а доступа в интернет он не дает. Это сложно описать в двух словах, но я думаю что вы приблизительно поняли о чем я говорю.

Comment: Другие приложения на этом телефоне работают нормально, подключаются к интернету. А также с этим моим домашним роутером работают 3 компьютера, ноутбук, 2 других смартфона и планшет. Прямо сейчас я пишу с компа, подключенного к этому роутеру.

Comment: значит проблема точно в телефоне, так как сброс не помог, то значит нужно посмотреть может mac адрес не так прописан, чисто гипотетически

Comment: а в каком примерно разделе мак адрес посмотреть в андроиде, не знаешь?

Comment: а какой телефон, мне просто легче будет ориентироваться)

Comment: телефон xiaomi redmi 3

Comment: в настройках должна быть строка поиска настроек, там вводите mac и вам выведет где находится ваш мак адрес

Comment: Мне кажется что проблема у вас в DNS. Попробуйте на роутере использовать публичные DNS сервера от гугла или яндекса, и их же выдавать по DHCP клиентам. Проблема должна уйти.